# Using ffmpeg for mp3 conversion: could not find codec parameters / unspecified frame size

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, codec

I have an mp3 file that I can't play with any of my audio players that I have on Windows 8, so I decided to convert it using ffmpeg.
I downloaded it from a website, which was able to play the mp3. I want to keep 497 seconds from the 219th second onwards.

```
ffmpeg -ss 219 -t 497 -i INPUT.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 9 OUTPUT.mp3
```

I believe I was correct using this command, but ffmpeg gives the following output:

```
ffmpeg version N-58456-ga9a3afe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 25 2013 22:01:38 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 54.100 / 52. 54.100
  libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavformat    55. 21.102 / 55. 21.102
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mp3 @ 003beaa0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
bitcoin_spraakherkenning.mp3: could not find codec parameters
```

Do I need to specify the framesize / analyzeduration / probesize values? And if so, how?

Comment: If none of the audio players (which ones, actually?) can play it, then the file must be broken, and ffmpeg will also not be able to convert it. How exactly do you mean, "which was able to play the mp3"? Did you make sure the download itself isn't corrupt? How are you certain the file you downloaded was the exact same as used on said website?

Comment: That said, you could try with a more recent ffmpeg build. Yours is already more than a year old. http://ffmpeg.org/download.html